# Error linking Azure Blob Storage account to Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created an Azure Data Factory and I am trying to create a new linked service to using an Azure Blob Storage account. The connection test passes successfully, but each time I try to link the service I am greeted with the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
```

I am using the Azure Data Factory V2 and the service I am trying to link is a StorageV2 storage account.

Not quite sure where to go from here, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this afternoon I have been having the same issue (it worked last Friday). It occurred trying to create linked services for Azure Storage or SQL Database. I tried various browsers, different Azure subscriptions, different client machines, deploying Data Factory and storage accounts in different regions and probably a few other things that I have forgotten now.

Ultimately, I just gave up on the portal and created the linked services from PowerShell which worked just fine.

```
$resourceGroupName = "<Resource group name>"
$dataFactoryName = "<Data factory name>"
$storageAccountName = "<Azure storage account name>"
$storageAccountKey = "<Azure storage account key>"

## JSON definition of the linked service. 
$storageLinkedServiceDefinition = @"
{
    "name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$storageAccountName;AccountKey=$storageAccountKey",
                "type": "SecureString"
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

## IMPORTANT: stores the JSON definition in a file that will be used by the Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService command. 
$storageLinkedServiceDefinition | Out-File c:\AzureStorageLinkedService.json

## Creates a linked service in the data factory
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "AzureStorageLinkedService" -File c:\AzureStorageLinkedService.json
```

Comment: I ended up going with a different solution after finding out that Postgres is not a sink for data factories. Thank you for the detailed answer though!

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, I received feedback from Microsoft that this was a bug in the ADF portal and that a fix has been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I was logged in with 2 different accounts. I logged out of both, signed in with one and it worked. Hope this helps you.